# Don't understand the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and defining 
>   $$
> F(x) = \int_a^x \! f(t) \, dt
> $$ 
>   for $x \in [a, b]$, then $F'(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in (a,b)$.

I don't understand what function the variable $t$ is for.  What is the definition of $f(t)$?  And is $F(x)$ a set?  Because it seems like $\int_a^x$ can have varying answers depending on what $x$ is.

Comment: [Related](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7694/how-to-convince-students-of-the-integral-identity-int-0afxdx-int-0afa-x).

Comment: $f(t)$ could be any continuous function on $[a,b]$. $F(x)$ is a function as well.

Comment: Wow @GitGud The top answer for that question explains so much about my confusion..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remember that a function is like a machine where you for each input there is exactly one output. We usually write $y = f(x)$ when $x$ denotes the input and $y$ denotes the output. $f$ is the function (rule) that tells you how you can find $y$ given $x$.

Ok, so now let's say that you have a function $f$. Let's call the input variable $t$. So for each number $t$ you get the (output) number $f(t)$. Now, given two numbers $a$ and $b$, you can find the integral
$$
\int_a^b f(t)\; dt.
$$
This integral gives you a number. Here we use $t$ in $f(t)$ and $dt$ to say that $t$ is the (input) variable for the function $f$.

Now if you choose another $b$ then you will get another number for the integral. So, for example, you might have
$$
\int_a^5 f(t)\;dt, \quad 
\int_a^8 f(t)\;dt, \quad
\int_a^{11.5} f(t)\;dt.
$$
So, you actually have a function. Let's call the input variable for this function $x$ (we don't want to use the same variable as the one for $f$). So for each (input) number $x$ we get a number (output):
$$
\int_a^x f(t)\;dt
$$
If $x=5$ then you get $\int_a^5 f(t)\;dt$ (a numbers).

We haven't given this function a "name", so let's call it $F$ (again we don't want to call it $f$ because we already have a different function with that name).

So for each input $x$ you get the output $F(x)$ and this is defined by
$$
F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\; dt.
$$
This is then a new function - a function who's output depends on the input $x$. What the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells you is that (under the given assumptions) this function is differentiable (that is you can find the derivative) with derivative
$$
F'(x) = f(x).
$$
So, for example
$$
F'(5) = f(5).
$$
Remember that the derivative of a function is just a new function. So again we have an output ($F'(x)$) for each input $x$. The way you calculate the output of the derivative of $F$ is by evaluating $f$ at the input.

Comment: I don't understand something about the theorem. If we put $x=b$ in $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\; dt$, we'd get $F(b) = \int_a^b f(t)\; dt$; but shouldn't the LHS be equal to $F(b) - F(a)$? Where did the second term disappear?

Comment: @MrReality: Yes, and what is $F(a)?$

Comment: From what I know, $F(a)$ is the value of the function $F(x)$ at $x=a$, right?

Comment: @MrReality: Yes, and $F(a) = \int_a^a f(t)\; dt = ?$

Answer (score 9):

Well, the other answers are very satisfactory and more than sufficient for dealing with the problem, but I'd like to expose another point of view...

**I hate this notation.**

You don't integrate $f(t)$ on $[a,b]$. You integrate a *function* $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on $[a,b]$. This is illustrated by the presence of the so-called "dummy variable" being not only useless and immaterial, but also confusing. We can re-write it simply by

$$\int_a^b f(t)dt=\int_a^b f$$

And (with Lebesgue's Theory in mind), we get the much more illuminating notation:

$$\int_{[a,b]}fd\mu$$

$[a,b]$ is the set we are integrating over, and $\mu$ is the measure we are considering, which we can simply omit from notation in most cases when dealing with calculus, since we take the lebesgue measure.... arriving at:

$$\int_{[a,b]}f$$

Now, we define, for $x \in [a,b]$, a function $F:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by:

$$F(x)=\int_{[a,x]}f$$

Note that we are changing the set we are integrating over when we change $x$. The fundamental theorem of calculus is simply stating that if $f$ is continuous at $x$, then:

$$F'(x)=f(x)$$

*Note*: An "argument" for the notation is that it makes the theorem of change of variables intuitive. I disagree. It makes the theorem of change of variables (arguably) more easily manageable and prone to good memorizing and calculation, but it is as far as it goes. The intuition is independent of notation. Even with this "advantage", I find the theorem much less confusing theoretically when stated like this:

$$ \int_{[\phi(a), \phi(b)]} f=\int_{[a,b]} f\circ \phi . \phi '$$

Comment: Only answer that makes sense here

Answer (score 2):

Inside the integral, the variable $t$ is a "dummy$ variable in that it is only a label.

One can use any "lablel" for the dummy variable.  To wit,

$$\int_a^x f(t) dt = \int_a^x f(u) du = \int_a^x f(v) dv $$

etc.

The result of the integration is a function of $x$, $F(x)$.

NOTE:  $F$ is also a function of $a$, but $a$ is typically viewed as a fixed parameter.

Comment: Your remark about the lower limit $a$ is amusing. I believe the upper limit was made variable $x$ to get the nice relation $F'(x) =f(x) $. If instead the upper limit was fixed as $b$ and the lower limit was $x$ we would get a negative sign $F'(x) =-f(x) $. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you as always.  And yes, if we write $F(a,x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$, then $\frac{\partial F(a,x)}{\partial a}=-f(a)$

Answer (score 2):

$t$ is a dummy variable so in a sense it's just there for notation. Think of $\sum_{t=1}^nt = n(n+1)/2$. It doesn't really matter what $t$ is as it doesn't appear in the simplified form, but it **does** matter what $n$ is. $F(x)$ is a function on $[a,b]$ which is sometimes called the 'antiderivative' of $f(x)$. The definition of $f(t)$ may be anything as long as it's continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The FTC is actually a very intuitive concept that is not really anything special to just calculus. Here is an explaination with absolutely no math. The FTC basically says that the sum of small changes within a bound sums up so that the resultant affect (Net effect) only occurs at the bounds. Now here's a little math $dF =f(t)dt $ the sum of $dF$ (infintesmaly differences in $F $), which is the integral in the theorem is equivalent to just the difference of $F $ across the bounds $F (b)-F (a) $. Now why is this intuitive...here is a trivial but helpful example let's setup the sum $x_1-x_2+x_2-x_3+x_3-x_4$ what does this cancel to? $x_1-x_4$. $x_1$ and $x_4$ are the bounds. That is basically the FTC at work in a very trivial way. This allows us to also realize that the multivariable integral theorems ,Stokes, divergence and the Line FTC are all restatements  of the same 1D FTC just boosted up a dimension. Hope this helps! I think intuition is best.

Comment: I don't think this is very clear at all; what's "changing within a bound"? It's not clear here what even is doing the changing.

Comment: $f (t) $ is the rate of change of $F $ I thought the knowledge of the derivative could be assumed, so $dF $ is the change in $F $. Definite integrals are bounded, hence "bounds".

Comment: But there is no change inside the interval when we move the bound. All that is happening is that we are adding more area on one side of the given region. Nothing changes on the inside. I also do not think that explicit differential notation is a good idea; it inevitably leads to a long discussion about what exactly differentials mean.

Comment: Well there's a change in the value of the function $F $ across the interval, assuming not constant. The definite integral is equivalent to the net change in the function $F (a)-F (b) $ across the bound. Although differentials are not well defined it still an infinitesimal difference...I see this as being better explaination then using the typical area explaination.

Comment: I am not talking about any change in $f(t) $ the function whose area we are computing I don't know if that is clear. I am talking about its antiderivative

Answer (score -1):

A simple and concise answer is as follows:

$$F(x)=∫_a^b f(x)\,dx$$

Therefore,

$$F(x)=f(b)-f(a)$$

So $F(x)$ is the integral of $f(x)dx$ from $a$ to $b$ , right? All the fundamental theorem of Calculus is saying is that along this set (interval $a,b$) exists the inverse operation:

$$F'(x)=f(x) $$

Comment: Thank you for reformatting!

Comment: The equation $F(x) =f(x) - f(a) $ is wrong. I suspect a typo here.

Comment: Should be f(b) not f(x). Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: On further inspection I think there are further mistakes. First one seems to be a typo. Your first equation should be $$F(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$$ as given in question. And the second equation $F(x) =f(b) - f(a) $ does not make sense here. Your final equation $F'(x) =f(x) $ is correct however (and this equation is more popular by the name of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).

Comment: X and b can be the same thing. "t" here is a dummy variable. There is nothing different between our two equations other than calling one thing "t" ,etc. Calling b "x" and then calling x "t" on the r.h.s of the first equation is just a preference. You will see upon inspection that x = b.

Comment: $∫_a^b f(x)\,dx$ is just a constant independent of x